# How to set space between plot and colormap table

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using secondary y-axis and cmap color but when I plot together the color bar cross to my plot

here is my code

```
fig,ax1=plt.subplots()


ax1 = df_Combine.plot.scatter('Parameter2', 'NPV (MM €)', marker='s', s=500,   ylim=(-10,60),  c='Lifetime1 (a)', colormap='jet_r', vmin=0, vmax=25, ax=ax1)
graph.axhline(0, color='k')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)


ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(df_Combine_min_select1["CumEnergy1 (kWH)"])


plt.show()
```

and here is my plotting

[image]

anyone can help how to solve this issue?

Thank you

Comment: @BigBen, I did but it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you let pandas automatically create a colorbar, you don't have positioning options. Therefore, you can create the [colorbar](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html) in a separate step and provide the `pad=` parameter to set a wider gap. Default, `pad` is `0.05`, meaning 5% of the width of the subplot.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

df_Combine = pd.DataFrame({'Parameter2': np.random.rand(10) * 10,
                           'NPV (MM €)': np.random.rand(10),
                           'Lifetime1 (a)': np.random.rand(10) * 25,
                           })
ax1 = df_Combine.plot.scatter('Parameter2', 'NPV (MM €)', marker='s', s=500, ylim=(-10, 60), c='Lifetime1 (a)',
                              colormap='jet_r', vmin=0, vmax=25, ax=ax1, colorbar=False)
plt.colorbar(ax1.collections[0], ax=ax1, pad=0.1)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(np.random.rand(10))

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thank you mate, it solved now. Thank you also for your explanation, it help me to get better understand